# Does deleting a pointer delete the memory it's pointing too?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

If I have a pointer like so:

```
int *test = new int;
```

And I create another pointer that points to `test` like so:

```
int *test2 = test;
```

Then I delete `test2`:

```
delete test2;
```

Does that mean that it will delete the memory of `test` as well, or would I have to call `delete test` also?

Comment: you don't really "delete a pointer", you free the memory it *points to*.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the memory will be <del>deleted</del> freed as both pointers point to the same memory.

Furthermore, `test` will now be a **dangling pointer**(as will `test2`) and dereferencing it will result in **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Alright thanks for the quick answer and I believe you answered my last question. So if I have a function and i call it like this Function(new Childclass) and if i have a pointer pointing to that within that in the function like so void Function(BaseClass *instance) { childInstance = instance; } if I delete childInstance it will also delete the instance parameter as well and therefore no memory leaks?

Comment: Also, "a double delete" (trying to free the same memory twice) is undefined behavior.

Comment: @user1583115 Please don't do that though. Use `std::shared_ptr`. Don't roll your own when it's already in the standard library.

Answer (score 8):

You never delete the memory for `test`, nor do you delete the memory for `test2`. The only thing that ever gets deleted is the *object* `*test`, which is identical to the object `*test2` (since the pointers are the same), and so you must only delete it once.

This is a very common and very unfortunate misnomer that propagates and spoils the minds of people new to C++: One often speaks colloquially of "freeing a pointer" or "deleting a pointer", when you really mean "freeing memory to which I have a pointer", or "deleting an object to which I have a pointer". It's true that the relevant constructions (i.e. `std::free` and `delete`) take as their argument a pointer to the entity in question, but that doesn't mean that the pointer itself is operated on -- it merely communicates the *location* of the object of interest.