# Assignment operator and Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, delete-operator

I had recently asked a question somewhat related to this one, but it was horridly worded and I had no clue what I was doing. I got some time to play around with code and hope this question makes more sense. Nevertheless something is still going on wrong. I have a class B. A pointer (*p) to that class. I just want to make a copy of this pointer ( say called q). Delete p but still have q a valid pointer pointer to that same information that p was pointings too. Then delete q. When I try to set them equal to each other I get issues

```
class B
{
    public:
    B(); ~B();
    B(const B &Overloading);
    B& B::operator=(const B &Overloading);
    vector<*A> stores_a; //class A contains ints, doubles etc. I filled this with
    //pointers to class A
    void Mr_Clean();
};

B::B() {}
~B::B()
 {
    Mr_Clean();
 }
 B::B(const B &Overloading)
 {
     for(size_t i=0; i<stores_a.size(); i++)
     {
         stores_A[i]=new A(*Overloading.stores_a[i]);
     }
  }
B::B& B::operator=(const B &Overloading)
  {
      if(this!=&Overloading)
      {   Mr_Clean(); 
          for(size_t i=0; i<stores_a.size(); i++)
          {
              stores_A[i]=new A(*Overloading.stores_a[i]);
           }
      }
      return *this 
 }
 void B::Mr_Clean()
 {
    for(size_t i=0; i<stores_A.size(); i++)
    {
        delete stores_A[i];
    }
 }
 int main()
 {
       B *p=new B;
       B *q=new B;
       // fill some stuff. this is just random stuff I am making up
       *q=*p; //compiles then Kaboom at this line
        delete p;
        delete q;
      return 0;
  }
```

I guess I have some conceptual gap still on the assignment operator. I have read many tutorials and I feel like I am doing what they say...

Also another question, say in this example I also had a member int x in B. Since I called the copy constructor and overloaded the assignment operator do I have to explicitly call x=Overloading.x? I mean technically I am overriding the default copy constructor no? However x is just a regular plain old int.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11855379/596781) can help with some fundamental confusion about "deleting a pointer".

Comment: In your opening paragraph, you seem to be confusing pointers and objects. The pointer is `p`, and the object itself is `*p`.

Comment: Post real code, reduced to the minimum that will compile and run and show the problem. This code won't compile.

Comment: Sorry I worded the pointer part badly. Yes p is a pointer. *p would be the object it points to. I delete p ie. the object it points to but before I do that I want to make a copy of this object where q will point to this object. So when I delete what p points to, q will still point to a valid object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. You don't resize destination `vector`. But this doesn't cause any errors at the moment **because**
2. You use size of destination `vector` to loop through items of source `vector`. And this can cause runtime error.

You could try using this code to copy vectors:

```
stores_a.resize(Overloading.stores_a.size());
for(size_t i=0; i<Overloading.stores_a.size(); ++i)
{
    stores_a[i]=new A(*Overloading.stores_a[i]);
}
```

or this one (though the one above should be faster for general case):

```
stores_a.clear();
for(size_t i=0; i<Overloading.stores_a.size(); ++i)
{
    stores_a.push_back(new A(*Overloading.stores_a[i]));
}
```

Comment: haha I cant believe I made a dumb mistake like that. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is that you are calling copy constructor inside the assignment operator which allocates memory to the object. Then inside the body of the copy constructor, you again allocate them some memory. This is causing memory leak.
Inside the assignment operator, just insert some data into the object, do not allocate memory again.
Check the link of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)) or this one here if you specifically want help on [assignment operator](http://codingmash.com/c/overloading-assignment-operator/)

Comment: I was under the impression that the line *q=*p would call the overloaded assignment operator ie. (*q).operator=(*p) since I have already initialized q.